When is the spectrum of T the closure of the set of eigenvalues?
All the examples of operator which I know (not many...), we either have $\text{sp}(T) = \text{cl}(\text{eigen}(T))$, or $\text{eigen}(T)= \emptyset$ and $\text{sp}(T)\neq \emptyset$.
I'm wondering what conditions can we require to have always $\text{sp}(T) = \text{cl}(\text{eigen}(T))$?
One obvious, I think, would be to have $T$ surjective, or any equivalent condition, which would make $\text{sp}(T) = \text{eigen}(T)$. However, I wonder if there are other non-obvious conditions...
Typo:
I meant $T-\lambda I$  surjective, then $T-\lambda I $ invertible is equivalent to $T-\lambda I$ being injective.

Surjectivity or invertibilty of $T$ does not imply anything concerning the spectrum, as $T-\lambda I$ is invertible for $|\lambda|>|T|$ and the nature of $\sigma(T)$ and $\sigma(T-\lambda I)$ is the same. If $T$ is compact then by the Fredholm alternative if $0\neq\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

@RyszardSzwarc Typo, I meant $T-\lambda I$  surjective, then $T-\lambda I $ invertible is equivalent to $T-\lambda I$ being injective. It was in this sense that I wrote the original post.

I don’t know if this counts as non-obvious, but any diagonal operator satisfies this condition, so in particular any normal compact operator satisfies this condition. (In fact, if $T$ is normal, then $T = T_a \oplus T_d$ where $T_a$ is unitarily conjugate to a diagonal operator and $T_d$ has no eigenvalue. Then the condition is equivalent to that the closure of the set of diagonal entries of $T_a$ contains the spectrum of $T_d$ (except possibly $0$ when $T_d = 0$). For compact normal operators, $T_d = 0$, so the condition is automatically satisfied.)

@DavidGao Thanks for your comment. I'll need to learn more to understand what you've just wrote... The book I'm using for self-study seems to be simpler. Thanks anyway. ;)
